# How to remove yarn packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6, tailwind-css

I followed the instructions at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation and https://web-crunch.com/posts/how-to-install-tailwind-css-2-using-ruby-on-rails to install tailwind as follows

```
~/code/example % yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
✨  Done in 3.87s.
```

When I try to remove it to install the latest version I get this error:

```
~/code/example % yarn remove tailwindcss @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat
yarn remove v1.22.4
[1/3]   Removing module tailwindcss...
[2/3]   Removing module @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/remove for documentation about this command.
```

I don't fully understand how removing yarn packages work -- could someone help?

Comment: Take a look at your `package.json` file, maybe the package is under a slightly different name there

Comment: my package.json looks like this: {
  "name": "example",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

If u have error

> `yarn install                                                               yarn install v0.27.5                                                      warning ../package.json: No license field [1/4] Resolving packages... success Already up-to-date. Done in 0.09s.`

Try this `npx clear-npx-cache` this work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem after upgrading from node `v16.10.0` to `v17.4.0`.
You can also use the latest stable version 16.13.2.
Afterwards you can clear your cache using `npm cache clean -f`
Then run your command again.